# Bringt "Impact" im Deutschen einen semantischen Gewinn?

Tags: anglicism, semantics

Der englische Begriff *impact* hat mehrere Bedeutungen: *Zusammenstoß, Einwirkung, Auswirkung, Einfluss,* im Zusammenhang mit einer Wirkung auch *Macht* oder *Gewalt.* Nach meiner Beobachtung hat sich *impact* zuerst als Bezeichnung für den Einschlag und die nachfolgende Wirkung eines Asteroiden auf der Erde im Deutschen etabliert. Mittlerweile steht es manchmal auch für Auswirkungen speziell auf die Umwelt, wenn es z. B. um den »ökologischen Fußabdruck« geht, und vermutlich wird es sich in diesem Sinn weiter verbreiten.

Beispiele:

> - Doch Fachleute wurden von dem Impakt überrascht
>   *[Spiegel online](http://www.spiegel.de/wissenschaft/weltall/asteroiden-gefahr-erde-ist-auf-einschlaege-aus-all-schlecht-vorbereitet-a-955924.html), Einschlag eines Asteroiden auf dem Mond*
> - Positiver Impact für Burgring No. 7
>   *[Nachricht über Pläne zur Modernisierung des Naturhistorischen Museums Wien](http://www.nhm-wien.ac.at/jart/prj3/nhm/main.jart?rel=de&content-id=1288702488978)*
> - Projekt *[Hall-Impact](http://www.nhm-wien.ac.at/jart/prj3/nhm/main.jart?rel=de&content-id=1389699851222)*
>   *Forschungsprojekt über Mensch, Landschaft, Umwelt in der Salzregion Bad Hall*
> - Impact auf die Umwelt
>   *[Ratgeber für Fleischersatzprodukte](http://www.bewusstkaufen.at/ratgeber/45/fleischersatzprodukte.html)*

Wer nicht im entsprechenden Fachgebiet arbeitet, hat keinen Einfluss auf die Verwendung als Fachbegriff, aber man kann sich sehr wohl entscheiden, ob man ein Fremdwort in den eigenen privaten Sprachgebrauch aufnimmt, solange es noch nicht so allgemein gebräuchlich ist, dass seine Vermeidung zwanghaft und sonderbar wirkt. Dass ein Wort im Duden steht, nimmt dem Einzelnen diese Entscheidung wohl nicht ab: Wörterbücher geben Auskunft über Verwendung und Verbreitung eines Wortes, sie entscheiden aber nicht über ihre sprachliche Sinnhaftigkeit. In meinen Augen ist das Wort so hässlich, dass ich es nicht ohne Not verwenden werde, zumal es, siehe oben, gute Alternativen im Deutschen gibt.

#### Meine Frage:

Bringt der Import von *impact* in den allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch einen semantischen Mehrwert? Oder handelt es sich nur um einen Akt konnotativer Aufwertung bzw., negativ ausgedrückt, sprachlicher Emigration?

Comment: Darüber habe ich nie nachgedacht, weil ich noch nie jemanden den Begriff im Deutschen benutzen gehört habe. *Ad multos annos!*

Comment: @KilianFoth Man hört ihn noch kaum im täglichen Gespräch, aber liest ihn schon immer wieder, und in populären TV-Sendungen über Asteroiden etc. wird er in der deutschen Fassung verwendet.

Comment: Ich denke, das eine oder andere Zitat würde der Frage zu mehr Impact verhelfen. Immerhin gibt es das Wort schon im Duden.

Comment: Die Bezeichnung für einen Meteoriteneinschlag wurde eingedeutscht: „Impa**k**t“ ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Impakt), [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impakt)).

Comment: Impact könnte, neben den allgemeinen Gründen Fremdwörter benutzen zu wollen, wegen seiner lautmalerischen Qualitäten, beliebt sein. Die Frage ist mir aber zu meinungslastig. Was ist schon nötig? Und dann gleich wirklich nötig?

Comment: @userunknown Wenn man so eine Frage ernst nimmt, ist sie nicht meinungslastig. Und leider wird die Frage von Bedeutungen eines Wortes allgemein nicht sehr ernst genommen, obwohl es auch bei scheinbaren Synonymen sehr viele und feine Unterschiede gibt. Der Titel soll übrigens Leser anlocken, die Frage ist, glaube ich, ziemlich klar formuliert.

Comment: Ich persönlich glaube, dass _Impakt_ oder _Impact_ zwar im Gegensatz zu vielen anderen Anglizismen keinen Mehrwert bringt, finde das Wort aber dennoch schön. Es gehört für mich zu der Sorte, die nicht bescheuert, sondern tatsächlich "cool" klingt.

Comment: Ich glaube, Impakt oder Impact hört (oder liest) man nur im Bezug auf ganz spezielle Themen und selbst dann nicht zwingend. Im Deutschen gibt es locker 1 Millionen solcher Wörter. Um die Frage zu beantworten: Nein, es ist nicht nötig. Warum? Ich hab's noch nie gebraucht oder gelesen/gehört. Bis gerade zumindest.

Comment: Vielleicht wäre ein Titel, der mehr auf die Semantik geht doch besser. Darum geht es dir ja in erster Linie. Den "Körper" der Frage lesen nicht immer alle so ganz genau weil Internet und so.

Comment: s. a. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_Factor

Answer (score 1):

Es ist schon ein paar Jahre her, dass man Impact-Drucker (also solche, die mit Typenrad oder Nadeln auf ein Farbband hämmern) von den Non-Impact-Geräten (Tintenstrahl, Laser) unterschieden hat; weil erstere inzwischen praktisch ausgestorben sind, hat sich diese (sinnvolle) Anwendung erübrigt.

Ansonsten halte ich das Wort für verzichtbar; da *Impact* aber viel kürzer ist als *Auswirkungen* (zwei Silben gegenüber vier) und den Anschein von höheren intellektuellen Weihen erweckt, wird eine weitere Ausbreitung aber nicht zu verhindern sein.

Comment: Wenn Du Auswirkung (Einzahl) mit Impact (Einzahl) vergleichst steht es nur noch 3:2. Ohne die Vorsilbe "Aus~" steht es dann Untentschieden. Wirkung und Einfluss haben auch nur 2 Silben.

Answer (score 1):

Ich kann auch nicht mit der Entdeckung eines semantischen Mehrwerts aufwarten, aber vielleicht mit einem etymologischen Hinweis.

Der englische Begriff ist teilweise fachsprachlich üblich im Bereich der Planung und Evaluierung von Projekten. So stammen etwa bestimmte Methoden zur Wirkungsmessung aus dem englischsprachigen Raum; deren Begrifflichkeiten werden dann ins Deutsche übernommen. In deinen Beispielen geht es bei zwei der drei Fälle mit englischer Schreibweise anscheinend um Projektberichte oder -darstellungen. Eine Übernahme von fachsprachlichen Termini in Materialien für die Außendarstellung und Öffentlichkeitsarbeit ist naheliegend, zumal es ja hier auch darum geht, die eigene Fachkompetenz zu unterstreichen.

Comment: Ein weiteres Beispiel aus der Etymologie ist der sogenannte Impact-Faktor von wissenschaftlichen Fachmagazinen, mit dem die Zitationswahrscheinlichkeit des Journals. Dieser Faktor gilt als wichtiges Mittel, um den Rang eines Journals zu bestimmen und ist ein entsprechendes für den Rang der Veröffentlichungen darin.